Necessary collision resistance of a nonce for replay protection
In request/response communication, replay protection can be implemented by exchanging a random number. For example, in its secure request, a client sends a random UID (nonce) to the server in addition to the payload, and this is sent back in the response. If the UID sent is the same as the UID received, this confirms to the client that the response relates to the associated request and that there is no replay.
I now want to dimension the bit length of the UID, and an important parameter for this is the collision probability. I know about the birthday paradox/attack, but I have problems determining/choosing the maximum collision probability. I think that a target collision probability of $1×10^{-6}$ is already too low and that $1×10^{-9}$ might be sufficient. But I'm not sure about this.
Are there any specific guidelines or papers that indicate the maximum collision probability a nonce should not exceed to implement replay protection?
